# WPF - XAML file shows Value cannot be null" error but project can still be run

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to WPF and have an error in my `MainWindow.xaml` file that appears to not hinder building or running the project which is strange to me.

In my `MainWindow.xaml`, I have:

```
<Window x:Class="MyP"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyProject.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyProject" Height="800" Width="1200">

    <Grid>
        <controls:LoginView></controls:LoginView>
        <controls:Screen1></controls:Screen1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The line `<controls:LoginView></controls:LoginView>` is showing a green squiggly line and when hovering over it, it reads: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString"

My `LoginView.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.View.LoginView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <Grid>...</Grid>
</UserControl
```

**LoginView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LoginView : UserControl
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what this error is referring to and how to resolve it?

Comment: What do you have inside `LoginView` grid and in code behind?

Comment: It appears that your `LoginView` expects you to bind to some property of it. Please show the entire code of it's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you put some code in your usercontrol's constructor and if you are injecting parameters via DI or making remote calls etc. in design time they throw exception.

```
if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    return;
// put the rest of your code here
```

Comment: Yeah, I've found that design view breaks with any sufficiently complex view/view-model relationship without the code Eldar has shown.